# Problems to access certain category using xpath in Rstudio

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, xml2

how are you? I am trying to access to a particular sportbetting web, i want to get the names of the football matches that are being played, but when i try i only get access to all the event names and i do not know why. I am using this code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

html="https://www.supermatch.com.uy/live_recargar_menu/"

a=rvest::read_html(html)

b2= a %>% html_node("body") %>% html_node(xpath="//li[@class='sport code_sport-1']") %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath="//span[@class='titulo']") %>% html_text()
```

As you can see, this code gets the name for all the events that are being played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page <- "https://www.supermatch.com.uy/live_recargar_menu/" %>%
  read_html()

tibble(
  title = page %>%
    html_elements(".titulo") %>%
    html_text(),
  score = page %>%
    html_elements(".marcador") %>%
    html_text(), 
  time = page %>%
    html_elements(".marcador+ span") %>%
    html_text() %>% 
    str_squish()
) 

# A tibble: 15 × 3
   title                                      score time         
   <chr>                                      <chr> <chr>        
 1 CS Emelec - Atletico Mineiro               0:1   1ª parte 18' 
 2 Nacional de Montevideo - Union de Santa Fe 1:0   1ª parte 18' 
 3 Brusque FC - Esporte Clube Bahia           0:1   PT 34'       
 4 Gremio FBPA - Londrina                     1:0   PT 34'       
 5 Fulgencio Yegros - Deportivo Santani       2:0   2ª parte 76' 
 6 Paraguay - Panama                          2:0   2ª parte 65' 
 7 Venezuela U20 - Bolivia U20                26:10 2do cuarto 6'
 8 Liu, L - Parikh, H                         1:1   3er set      
 9 Truwit, Teddy - Raab, J                    0:0   1er Set      
10 Ngounoue, M - Woog, M                      1:0   2do set      
11 Cheng, E - Lopez, Jackeline                1:0   2do set      
12 Moore, M - Pratt, S                        0:1   2do set      
13 Zhu, Jiayun - Horwood, S                   0:0   1er Set      
14 Nguyen, M - White, M                       0:0   1er Set      
15 Martincova, T - Pliskova, Karolina         0:0   No iniciado
```